# Change Application Name for existing Entity Framework connection?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I am trying to find a way to get the real user (not my Service Account) accessible inside of SQL Server without adding a parameter to each of my many thousands of SQL Queries.

One lead I am following is to put the user in the "Application Name".  This is defined in the connection string.  But, I still need to use Connection Pooling, and making a new connection for each user is performance prohibitive.

**So I wondering if there is a way to change the application name for an already existing connection?**  (Basically as a new call to the database is going to be made, I would update the Application to be the actual user that is making the call.)

Comment: You can't alter the connection once the connection is established. To do this in the connection would require adding the user to the ApplicationName element of the connection string before you make a connection. But as you noted, that means your connection pool is going to suffer.  I don't know of any way you can accomplish what you are trying to do.

Comment: Look into [`SESSION_CONTEXT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/session-context-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) (SQL 2016 +). You can set it for each user and it should work with connection pulling, though I have never tried. (If you have pre SQL 2016 DB, then look into CONTEXT_INFO())